# Magento Notification not rendering properly

Tags: magento-1.9, messages

We have used magento's default notification system to show messages in the front end. It was rendering properly. But suddenly it started to print the messages as plain string. Earlier we used to show the html tags along with the messages. But now it just shows a plaint text. When it checked the HTML of the message
it is showing as follows.

```
<ul id="admin_messages">Image uploaded successfully <b>TEST</b></ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is a `$_escapeMessageFlag` in `Mage_Core_Block_Messages`, which you have to set like this - mind the `->setEscapeMessageFlag(true)` This is the important part!

```
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->setEscapeMessageFlag(false)->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

Example comes from `app/design/frontend/<your_namespace|default>/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

Or you could just rewrite the following `Mage_Core_Block_Messages` Line 249

Original:

```
 $html.= ($this->_escapeMessageFlag) ? $this->escapeHtml($message->getText()) : $message->getText();
```

New:

```
$html.= $message->getText();
```

You should rewrite the method, never change core files.

Hope it helps :-)